# Codeigniter can not retrieve data from cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I am doing a project in codeigniter.Here i have inserted data into Cart codeigniter.But  I can not retrieve data from cart in view file,also tried some code given below,I am a newbie trying to learn code,therefore please help me in this regard. controller code:-

```
class Cart extends CI_Controller{
    //put your code here
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Cart_model');
        $this->load->library('cart');


    }
    public function add_to_cart(){
      $product_id= $this->input->post('product_id',true);
      $qty= $this->input->post('qty',true);
      $this->load->model('Cart_model');
      $category_info= $this->Cart_model->select_product_info_by_product_id($product_id);

      $data = array(
        'id'      =>$category_info->product_id,
        'qty'     => $qty,
        'price'   => $category_info->product_price,
        'name'    => $category_info->product_name,
        'options' => array('image' => $category_info->product_image)
);

$this->cart->insert($data);

$this->load->view('pages/cart_view',$data); ;

    }
}
```

Model code:-

```
class Cart_model extends CI_Model{
    //put your code here
    public function select_product_info_by_product_id($product_id) {
      $category_info= $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('tbl_product')
      ->where('product_id',$product_id)
      ->get()->row();
      return $category_info;
    } 
}
```

view code:-

```
<div class="table-responsive cart_info">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="cart_menu">
                            <td class="image">Item</td>
                            <td class="description"></td>
                            <td class="price">Price</td>
                            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                            <td class="total">Total</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                                      <?php $contents=$this->cart->contents();
 print_r($contents);
                                    foreach ($contents as $v_contents){


                                      ?>  
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cart_product">
                                <a href=""><img src="images/cart/one.png" alt=""></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_description">
                                <h4><a href=""><?php echo $v_contents['name']?></a></h4>

                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_price">
                                <p><?php echo $v_contents['price']?></p>
                            </td>

                            <td class="cart_quantity">
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $v_contents['qty']?>" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p class="cart_total_price"><?php echo $v_contents['subtotal']?></p>
                            </td>
                                                               <?php } ?>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
```

config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']=TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

Cart.php

```
public $product_name_rules = '[:print:]';
```

Here what i have tried given above but can not retrieve cart data in view.Please help me in this regard.

Comment: from the current docs: 
[the Codeigniter Cart Library is **DEPRECATED and should not be used**. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#shopping-cart-class)

Comment: @Vickel, thanks for your response.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html   please check this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Cart.php

public $product_name_safe = TRUE;

replace

public $product_name_safe = FALSE;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.